# How to identify a dead potentiometer?

Tags: identification, potentiometer, passive-components, markings

So, I've cracked open my Roland Micro Cube which is a portable 2W guitar amplifier with digital modelling. The issue I've had with it since recently is the tone control potentiometer. Here's a picture of the front panel:

[image]

As you can see, the tone control goes from LO to HI (whatever that means, a shelving filter perhaps?). However, recently the control started behaving strangely - it's pretty much either just bass to the left and overdone highs to the right. I suppose the potentiometer is dead, since it feels looser than other potentiometers next to it. So I opened the chasis and had a look at the control board:

[image]

I've desoldered the potentiometer in question. It had the same markings as the other ones next to it, and they're all Alps-branded. Here's a close-up of the markings:

[image]

This is after I have lifted the metal support housing off. The unit has been launched in 2004, so I tried to find an Alps catalog from back then, couldn't find one so I went with the current one. From [here](http://www.alps.com/prod/info/E/PDF/Potentiometer/TAPER.pdf) I think it's safe to guess 3B is their marking for a linear taper:

[image]

The tricky part is 10, 80 and 4C. I opened up current Alps catalog for 9mm potentiometers and narrowed it down to the horizontal single-shaft one, which would be the one on the far left (RK09L horizontal):

[image]

As the available values are 10k, 20k, 50k and 100k I guess it's safe to assume the pot is a 10k linear. Well, easy, just replace it, right? I've measured the pot just to be sure. Which... threw me off guard. I got 2M when turned all the way to the right and what's more it was drifting all over the place (in the 1.9M-2.1M) without me touching it. Turning the pot to the left I got a reading of 6R. I also found the pot also drifts somewhere in the middle, in the 400k-800k range, without touching it at all. Here's a [video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Tg1RGCHJ0YqOVGcJ3) to help you visualize the issue.

Is this behavior expected for a faulty potentiometer? Could it in fact be a 10k linear or are my assumptions wrong?

Comment: What do you actually expect from a broken potentiometer to behave like?

Comment: Don't know, I just wanted to ask if it means it's broken or if my assumptions are broken

Comment: If the markings on the other potentiometer are equal (thus same type), you can try to measure the good one and check for differences.

Comment: Yes, I asked first because I'd rather avoid risking a screwup on my side when desoldering. I'll try that and report back

Comment: Did it. Measured 4R-9.6k on another one. It's a B10K

Comment: 1B looks like linear. 3B looks like "volume control"

Comment: Nice catch, should do the business for a simple tone control though! Now let's shell out $2 for a replacement Alps pot, probably shipping will be more than that, so I'll grab a couple different things. Hate the PCB mount pots, I'd rather go with whatever pots and wire them up but there's not enough space